# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lightkurve'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use lightkurve but Jupyter notebook keeps telling me that there isn't any module named 'lightkurve'. I've tried to find a solution but can't find one that works.

I'm currently learning off [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2yD9JrqllA&list=WL&index=8&t=151s). Here's the code I've put into Jupyter notebook so far;

```
from lightkurve import search_targetpixelfile
pixelfile = search_targetpixelfile("KIC 8462852", quarter=16).download(quality_bitmask='hardest');
```

And I get this error;

```
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import lightkurve
      2 from lightkurve import search_targetpixelfile
      3 pixelfile = search_targetpixelfile("KIC 8462852", quarter=16).download(quality_bitmask='hardest')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lightkurve'
```

If you need more info let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These kinds of errors are mostly the result of the virtual environment not being set correctly. Are you sure you run `jupyter` and installed `lightkurve` on the same vnev?

Comment: I don't know what a vnev is, sorry. Could you explain it to me?